# How to access array within JSON and iterate in Jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

Here is my json:

```
{
 "Meals": {
    "title": "All the meals",
    "lunch": ["Turkey Sandwich", "Chicken Quesadilla", "Hamburger and Fries"]
 }
}
```

I am trying to pass the array to my jade view and iterate over each into a select dropdown

Here's my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var data = require('../mock/data.json');

var dataLists = Object.keys(data).map(function(value){
  return data[value]
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: dataLists, dataJSON: data });
});
```

In my jade view I pass

```
!{dataJSON} // This returns [object Object]
```

Is there a way to accesss the array via the object key???

```
!{dataJSON.Meals.lunch}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following to access lunch array for **jade** template:

```
p #{dataJSON.Meals.lunch}
```

where `p` is a paragraph tag.

---

Yes, you can iterate over the array like this:

```
  form (action="someAction")
   select (name="lunch")
    each val in dataJSON.Meals.lunch
     option (value= val)= val
```

for detail view you can refer: [Iteration in Jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Comment: Thanks @Nivesh. Do you know how I would access the raw array in my Jade template. I want to loop over it in a for loop like so: `form
   select
    for lunch in ["Turkey Sandwich", "Chicken Quesadilla", "Hamburger and Fries"]
     option(value=lunch) #{lunch}`

Comment: I finally figured that out after 30 mins of trying. Haha. Thanks again for helping!